# How "id" works in populating jsTree using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I am using the alternative JSON format to populate my jsTree as shown in this [link.](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)

**The problem is I can't find how the "id" attribute works in jsTree?**

In my case, both the parents can have same names sometimes. (Its not ideal but its a rare scenario that pops up so i have to handle it). So i use their unique "id's" in the tree. Now if the childern nodes of the parents have the same "id" as parent nodes, somehow the jsTree does not work on button click and keeps showing the "Loading.." message.

**My JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "3",         //Any value except 3 and 5 works
    "text": "Ford",
    "parent": "3",
    "icon": "fa fa-circle-o"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",        //Any value except 3 and 5 works
    "text": "Fiat",
    "parent": "5",
    "icon": "fa fa-circle-o"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "text": "Cars",
    "parent": "#",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "text": "Cars",
    "parent": "#",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"
  }
]
```

**My html code:**

```
 <div id="car-list" class="collapse">
                       #{MyBean.jsonString}
                   </div>
                   <h:outputScript>
                       $(function() {
                           var data1= JSON.parse(document.getElementById("car-list").innerHTML);
                           $('#car-list').jstree({
                               'core': {
                                   'data': data1
                               }
                           });
                       });
                   </h:outputScript>
```

where `jsonString` is a String object containing the above json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jstree every time I had 2 identical keys I could see only one element rendered instead of 2 (talking about the elements with the identical keys). In your case I imagine that the problem is that you have loops in your nodes so the rendering never ends. I surpassed my problem by creating keys from concatenation (parentKey_childKey). So in your case this would be:

```
[
  {
    "id": "3_3",         
    "text": "Ford",
    "parent": "3",
    "icon": "fa fa-circle-o"
  },
  {
    "id": "5_5",        
    "text": "Fiat",
    "parent": "5",
    "icon": "fa fa-circle-o"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "text": "Cars",
    "parent": "#",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "text": "Cars",
    "parent": "#",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"
  }
]
```

You can also see that multiple nodes with identical keys is not supported [here](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/592).

Comment: What do you mean by loops in the nodes?

Comment: You provide parentId equal with id. So somehow this tries to render the same node as parent and child at the same time.

Comment: Can you refer me the documentation where you read this behavior. As i mentioned in my question, i was unable to find the documentation that describes how "id" works

Comment: https://old.jstree.com/faq Here the old documentation says that jstree uses ids for jquery selectors. Html ids should be unique. As for the rendering process what I said is a suspicion since I do not participate to the implemenatation of jstree.